# Missing Expression Error when I try to convert the currency type

Tags: sql

I want to display the output of total price from my table as 'USD 20.00' or 'EURO 40' for US and Euro respectively.
I tired the following code and got the missing expression error.
How to convert it to the specified format?
The data type of the column 'price' is number.
My code goes here..

```
select convert(varchar(50),convert(money, coalesce(sum(nvl(CASE
    WHEN (typ=27 and l.tyt ='USD') THEN 'USD' + PRICE
    WHEN (typ=27 and l.tyt='EURO') THEN 'EURO'+ PRICE
    END,0)),0)),1) as Total from transactions;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the expression. 1) adding string value ('USD'/'EURO') to numeric value (PRICE), 2) NVL() on different data type, 3) SUM() on a string data. Anyone of these could be the cause of the error.

If the table stores differently denominated prices, you cannot sum them into on row - which one do you want to be in the result (EURO or USD). If you want to have both in two rows, the the following should work (note that in your original statement, the alias l is undefined so this is not likely to work):

```
SELECT 'USD', Sum(price) as Total
FROM transactions
WHERE typ=27 and tyt ='USD'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EURO', Sum(price) as Total
FROM transactions
WHERE typ=27 and tyt ='EURO'
```

or simply

```
SELECT tyt, Sum(price) as Total
FROM transactions
WHERE typ=27
GROUP BY tyt
```